# How to match a script using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

script 1:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=athenelive&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/athenelive" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from AtheneLIVE on www.twitch.tv</a>
```

script 2:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=athenelive&popout_chat=true" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
```

If user paste the script in same format i want to enable the done button of popup,otherwise i want to disable the done button.I want to perform this in javascript as a validation for both script 1 & script 2.

Need help.

I tried this,

```
var matches = $('#embed_url').val().match(/<iframe.*src=\"(.*)/);

and

var twitch = $('#embed_url').val().match(/<a.*href=\"(.*)/);
```

Not working for both script 1 & script 2.

This is my validation i tried to work with youtube video which is working

```
var matches = $('#youtube_url').val().match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
```

Comment: A little confused what you want. Do you want to extract: http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive from script 1 and http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=athenelive&popout_chat=true from script 2?

Answer (score 1):

For those 2 scripts the following will work, but be careful, are you sure the URLs for twitch.tv are always the same?

Script 1 - Regex

```
match('/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitch.tv\/widgets\/live_embed_player.swf\?channel=(.+?)[\"&\']/');

Array
(
    [0] => http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=athenelive"
    [1] => athenelive
)
```

Script 2 - Regex

```
match('/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitch.tv\/chat\/embed\?channel=(.+?)[\"&\']/');

Array
(
    [0] => http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=athenelive&
    [1] => athenelive
)
```

This will match the following and give you the channel name incase you want it?

Comment: Urls are always same and i want to allow user to add the script if the pasted script is in the above format.

Comment: So it this correct or do you wish to combine both into the same regex?